# java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, android

Пробою писать виджет погоды для android. Информацию о погоде хочу брать с сайта openweathermap.org. И на этом этапе происходят странные вещи. Если урл запроса открывать с устройства в браузере, то информация приходит с сайта. А вот так не работает почему-то:

```
private String getWeatherInJSON(float longitude, float latitude){
    StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();
    String sourceUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
            latitude + "&lon=" + longitude;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(sourceUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(strLine);
            }
            input.close();
        }
        httpconn.disconnect();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("myLog", "" + e.toString());
        return WRONG_RESPONSE;
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

Координаты вводятся нормальные(53.9000,27.5500 - Минск).

Выдает ошибку:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.openweathermap.org": No address associated with hostname

Comment: А разрешение на интернет прописали в манифесте?

Comment: Вы видимо забыли прописать в манифесте : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @Mikalai Оформите свой комментарий, как ответ и отметьте его верным - это может помочь еще кому-нибудь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо! Действительно не правильно были прописаны права. Странно что это студия подсказала написать:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
```

и вот так не пашет. Попробовал написать:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

и всё заработало.